# List management on the latest version of the Facebook website

Tags: facebook, friend-list

*This applies to the Facebook website*

The help section on Facebook's site has articles pertaining to how [lists can be created, managed and deleted](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/204604196335128) but all this material applies to a version of Facebook that I have been moved on from.

**On the latest version of the site, I am trying to find a way to see all my custom lists, see who is a part of them and manage those lists.**

I am able to see if a particular friend is part of a list by going to my friends list, finding that friend and seeing what lists they are part of but this is a really cumbersome process.

---

Edit: a screenshot of what I see on my left menu

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hidden, but this is what I found.

1. In the left menu, find the section labeled *FRIENDS*
2. If you hover your mouse pointer over that section, a link *MORE* will appear. Click that.
3. Now you should see a list of the system-level lists that Facebook has (e.g., Close friends, Acquaintances), the lists automatically created for you (e.g., schools, former employers, etc.), and your custom lists.
4. Click the list you want to manage. (Delete the list or add it to your favorites by clicking the pencil icon instead.)
5. On the right-hand side will be a heading "In this list" with some number in parentheses, just above some small thumbnail images of other profile photos. Next to that is a link *See All*
6. Click that link and you'll get a popup where you can search for people to add or click the X in a profile photo to remove that person

Comment: I have edited the question to show what I see on the left menu. I don't see a section labelled `FRIENDS`.

Comment: @karancan: Are you accessing this through a desktop browser? If so, then I suggest that you're not looking at the latest Facebook. What country are you in?

Comment: Yes, desktop. Canada.